# solucionar el anclaje

Tags: html5

Tengo un problema con mi anclaje de mi pag web one page, es que no no se posiciona  el  anclaje en la posición que quiero si no por defecto se ancla unos niveles mas arriba como puedo solucionar eso!?

```
<li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 9px;">
                    <a class="nav-link; btn btn-outline-warning" href="#noti" style="color: white;background-color:#f25d25; margin-right: 9px;">
                        Noticias
                    </a>
</li>

/*--------------------------- CONTENIDO----------------*/

<section>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="centralizar">     
<a id="Contacto">
                                </a>               
                        <h3>
                            CONTÁCTANOS
                        </h3>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    <label for="nombre_ape">
                                        Nombre y Apellido
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="nombre_ape" id="validationDefault01" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required="" type="text">
                                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                                        Muy Bien!
                                    </div>
                                </input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="validationDefaultUsername">
                                    Correo Electronico
                                </label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">
                                            @
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" class="form-control" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="correo electronico"
                                    required="" type="text" />
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Por favor introduzca un correo electronico valido!
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese El texto Aquí" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">
                            Enviar
                        </button>
                    </br>
                </form>
            </br>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
/*-----------------------------------FIN DEL CONTENIDO-------------------------------------------*/
```

no se posiciona en la posición que quiero la sección de CONTENIDO h3 si no en uno niveles mas arriba  como puedo solucionar esto :( ¿?

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto el anclaje lo defini de esta forma

```
  <h3>
    <a href="#Contacto">
       CONTÁCTANOS
    </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

de esta forma fue como  solucione el error de mi anclaje colocando un atributo como inicio en la botonera   el atributo href=#contacto-id
y en donde se quiere anclar en el  de container le agregue  el atributo id=contacto-id
fue como solucione mi error! 
---------------ejemplo-----------------

                    
                        Noticias

/*--------------------------- CONTENIDO----------------*/

```
                    <h3>
                        CONTÁCTANOS
                    </h3>
```

/*-----------------------------------FIN DEL CONTENIDO-------------------------------------------*/